# jBox not returning content

Tags: jquery, jbox

I am trying to use jBox (by Stephan Wagner) but I can't get my modal window to display a web page. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

new jBox('Modal', {
width: 900,
height: 550,
url: 'http://www.google.com',
},
reload: 'strict'
}).open();

});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the ajax options, your code should work just fine when you use it in the ajax object: https://stephanwagner.me/jBox/options#ajax

Also, you can only use webpages that have the access control header set, check this fiddle with updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/7hh5a6oc/

```
new jBox('Modal', {
  width: 900,
  height: 550,
  ajax: {
    url: '//www.google.com',
    reload: 'strict'
  }
}).open();
```

Following error will come up: `"XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access."`

So basically, webpages don't like to be loaded from unknown sources. You can always load content via ajax when it is allowed, see this fiddle which uses ajaxresponse.com: https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/569y8wcp/

You can also experiment with iframes, see this fiddle about that: https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/569y8wcp/2/ (We add an iframe with a webpage once the jBox is created). But again, it only works if the webpage allows to be loaded from external sources (Like my webpage: https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/569y8wcp/3/)

Comment: Hi is there a way to make your example code in "https://jsfiddle.net/StephanWagner/569y8wcp/3/" fire when a link is clicked. Again, many thanks for your help. I am learning.